# Download a file (with chrome on the node) and saving it on the server file system

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I must test if pdfs file are downloaded when clicking on a link. 
I've set a default folder to be able to download them with selenium  but I need to save my these of the server instead of the node.

```
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\SOIF\\Temp\\downloads");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

I tried to use:

```
((RemoteWebDriver) getWebDriver()).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector())
```

but this only works if I try to upload a file from the server with the node.

Is this even possible without setting the default download folder on the server?

Comment: Node is also windows?

Comment: Yes everything is windows

Comment: Can you try `"download.default_directory", "Z:\\shared_server_path\\SOIF\\Temp\\downloads"`

Comment: yes I can use a newtwork drive (doesnt even need a letter) but thats not what I want, I wanted to save it on the server (because I have acceptance, devs,... servers, saving it to the same directory doesnt make any sense.

Comment: the server where my java backend is running*

Comment: So what I was trying to do is indeed not possible, I guess I'll have to make the download directory info (with testcase Id) availiable when I create my webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Share a folder from your server. Then map it all your nodes with Map drive letter and once the mapping in done. You can use that path in all your test for download as well testing if the file was downloaded

`Z:` is the most common one used but you can use it with any other letter driver. and then use those paths only.

Example like @DebanjanB mentioned `"Z:\\shared_server_path\\SOIF\\Temp\\downloads"`

**Edit-1**

If you need to have separate download for each of your Test case then you have a possible option of doing below. Before starting the Webdriver, generate a UUID string and append that to your download folder

```
`"Z:\\shared_server_path\\SOIF\\Temp\\downloads\\fd411526-e3aa-43b1-a351-e484da4508d9"`
```

Create this folder and launch the webdriver with this as the download directory. When the test finish you can always know what the Test Case Name was. Create the directory

`"Z:\\shared_server_path\\SOIF\\Temp\\downloads\\TestCase1"`

And move the files to that folder. That is workable solution I can think of

Comment: Yes thats the solution I was trying to... but its not optimal because I need a specific folder for each testcase and I have not this info when I'm creating the webdriver. I dont think you can change capabilities without creating a new WebDriver. That's why I was trying to have a cleaner solution

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, seems viable and easier than reworking my webdriver logic

Comment: Now I have another problem, there is no way to get that info from the webdriver. There is no download.default_directory in capabilities

Comment: Why you want to get the value from driver? You set it up so you will have the value in your code?

Comment: Edit : I found a workaround. I go to chrome://settings and find the option value there. old message :  I could but it will be difficult (I get my webdrivers via a WebDriverFactory class where all the profiles and options are set). But if some of these settings are random, if I dont store it I cant get it back (because Capabilities and DesiredCapabilities are weird classes)